# Having trouble using fprintf in a recursive function

Tags: c

I'm using a recursive function that given a directory, scans through it and prints out all the files and child directories. It also prints the file list to a txt file.

My stdout is:

```
    [test]
      [empty]
        [notreally]
          [real empty]
        - haha.txt
      - readme.txt
    - test2.c
    - test.c
```

Where the folders are in the []. This is what I expect the stdout to be but when I check my log.txt it isn't the same:

```
          [real empty]
        [notreally]
        - haha.txt
      [empty]
      - readme.txt
    [test]
    - test2.c
    - test.c
```

If I change the FILE *log = fopen(logFilePath,"a+"); to FILE *log = fopen(logFilePath,"w"); then the output to log.txt would be:

```
[test]
- test2.c
- test.c
.txt
```

Comment: Are you opening the log file and then immediately closing the log file in main?  Typo?

Comment: That's just to clear the contents of log before I run the program instead of having to do it manually every time.

Comment: opening it as "w" already does that.  It will truncate the file and start writing at position 0 if the file already exists.  You are opening, truncating, closing, opening, appending.

Comment: You do.  After you open and close it as "w" in main.  You are truncating the file and then appending to it.  It is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about the parens. This:

```
else
    printf("%*s- %s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
    fprintf(log,"%*s- %s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
```

should be

```
else {
    printf("%*s- %s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
    fprintf(log,"%*s- %s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
}
```

Also, don't open and close the file every time you see a file. Open it once for writing (`"w"`)and pass it to the function. Don't open the file for appending in the function, take the `fopen` out of the function.

Comment: You're opening the file for appending: `fopen(logFilePath,"a+");` Open for writing so the old content is erased (`"w"`)

Comment: Don't close/open the file every time when you visit a file/directory. Open it once and just pass the handle as another parameter of your recursive function.

Comment: If I do it like that then it won't be able to store the entire list of files. See main post for what it outputs if I change the "a+" to "w".

Comment: Don't worry. Open the file before calling the function, and pass the file handle to it, that's all.

Comment: I would do it like that from the start but this a project for school and we cannot modify the function arguments.

Comment: OK, in this case you need to remember to close the file before the recursive call to listdir.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please remember about marking the answer as correct.